# Appcelerator Titanium Mobile and Airpush

Tags: java, android, mobile, sdk

I am creating an Android app using Titanium Mobile.

How do I integrate Java code and libraries for monetization like 'Airpush'?

Comment: You develop a `Appcelerator Module` (which is Java code), integrate Airpush with it, make it act as a bridge between your Appcelerator code and Airpush functions, and then use that module in your app. Question related to Module here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13953640/243709

Answer (score 0):

You should export your project to eclipse than add the airpush sdk to your project.