# Appcelerator Module development : How to connect my Java source with the module

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have been trying to build a module in Appcelerator to let one Android library become available to Appcelerator platforms as well, but the documentation on Appcelerator site isn't helping me much. It's been two days since I am hitting walls.

I followed [Android Module Development Guide](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Android+Module+Development+Guide#AndroidModuleDevelopmentGuide-Creatingamodule) available on their site, but it doesn't specify many things, for example:

- It tells about creating a module from command line for a calculator, but doesn't write much about how to integrate the actual code.

I might be missing something, that's a possibility, so I am giving it a read once again.

But can anyone point me towards correct direction or make things a little more clear please?

Answer (score 2):

I am answering my own question, so that if someone comes here it helps them.

Turns out that I was hitting the older version of their documentation, called Wiki.

The newer version hosted at `docs.appcelerator.com` are more descriptive.

In this particular case, [these docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Development_Guide-section-29004945_AndroidModuleDevelopmentGuide-ImportingaModuleintoEclipse) helped me quite a lot.

Apart from this, following links helped too and I got a sample module built and running:

- [Titanium Module Concepts](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Module_Concepts)
- [Integrating an external library in an Android module](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/11/integrating-an-external-library-in-an-android-module.html)
- [Module Development Guide Reference Module for iOS and Android](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/10/module-development-guide-reference-module-for-ios-and-android.html)

Hope it helps someone.